# How do I have to configure gitweb and gitolite so they'll work together?

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

I am trying to make gitweb work with gitolite... but unsuccessful so far.
I am working on a RedHat Linux machine. A user called `git` exists.

gitolite is installed under: `/home/git`
Repository location: `/home/git/repositories`

Please note that, gitweb was working fine with plain vanilla git. Now i am trying to make it work with gitolite.

Here are what my files look like:

- `/etc/gitweb.conf`

  ```
  $projectroot = "/home/git/repositories";
  @git_base_url_list = qw(ssh://[MyHostName]/home/git/projects.list);
  $projects_list = "/home/git/projects.list"
  ```
- `/home/git/projects.list`

  ```
  myrepo1.git
  myrepo2.git
  ```
- `/home/git/.gitolite.rc`:

  ```
  $PROJECTS_LIST = $ENV{HOME} . "/projects.list";
  $GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS = "gitweb.url receive.denyNonFastforwards receive.denyDeletes";
  ```

What configuration have I missed?
I have not made any changes to Apache.

Web URL: `http://MyHostName/git`
This gives a 404 error saying - *No repositories found*.

Answer (score 13):

I recently set up gitolite and gitweb and found that `/etc/gitweb.conf` required *very* little configuration. What you have looks right to me. What are the permissions like on `/home/git/repositories`? You may find they are too restrictive. Try this out:

```
$ chmod -R 775 /home/git/repositories
```

That's what solved the issue for me, (though I imagine there's a more secure way to set up the permissions). If that works, I'd recommend just having a look into giving Apache (or whatever user account gitweb is being executed under) more fine-grained permissions over the repositories directory.

I also have this in my `.gitolite.rc`:

```
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS => 'gitweb\.(owner|description|category)',
```

so that the following works in `<gitolite-admin>/conf/gitolite.conf`:

```
config gitweb.owner         =   owner name
config gitweb.description   =   some description
config gitweb.category      =   some category
```

Comment: To be slightly more secure you could add the apache/www-data user to the gitolite group `usermod -a -G gitolite apache` and then do `chmod -R 750 /home/git/repositories` along with setting the gitolite variable `$REPO_UMASK = 0027;`

Comment: The $REPO_UMASK setting was particularly useful for me. chmod-ing the repositories directory works until the next time you update a repo and then permissions get reset to 700 on one of the files. Notice that the docs say the UMASK setting in gitolite is critical if you want to run gitweb: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/rc.html

Comment: Checking your cmd `chmod -R 775 /home/git/repositories`: User get full access, group also and others read and execute. Why so generous? I have a 500 error with curl localhost:1234 and had 755. Changing to 775 does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [Gitolite `contrib/gitweb.conf`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/contrib/gitweb/gitweb.conf) at the end of `/etc/gitweb_config.perl`.
In other words, you need to call a Gitolite function from your `gitweb.conf` perl file, otherwise the integration GitWeb-Gitolite will never work.

```
# check for (at least) "R" permission
    my ($perm, $creator) = &repo_rights($repo);
    return ($perm =~ /R/);
```

(here `repo_rights` is a method from [gitolite.pm](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gitolite.pm#L685))

Check the section "[helping with gitweb](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/3-faq-tips-etc.mkd#_helping_with_gitweb)".

The last lines you need to add at then end of `gitweb_config.perl` are:

```
use lib (".");
require "gitweb.conf.pl";
```

That way, you will avoid any "`500 - Internal Server Error syntax error at /etc/gitweb.conf`" error message.

If you don't have a `gitweb_config.perl` in which you declare `gitweb.conf.pl`, but directly "`gitweb.conf.pl`", then add "`use lib (".");`" as the first line of that file.

Comment: At the end of /etc/gitweb.conf exactly what line do i need to add? I tried adding this line: $/home/git/gitolite/contrib/gitweb.conf , but that gives error. I think i misunderstood.

Comment: I am doing something very obviously wrong. 

Is my gitweb.conf, projects.list, .gitolite.rc setup correctly?
Error message clearly says: No Projects Found.

Comment: @Jee: At the end of `/etc/gitweb.conf`, you ned to copy *all* the lines of https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/contrib/gitweb/gitweb.conf (and change the value of lines 21, 23, ... if you have used different paths in your Gitolite installation)

Comment: i get following error on webpage (it appears these new lines are not understood by gitweb, it gives syntax error at very first line):

500 - Internal Server Error 
syntax error at /etc/gitweb.conf line 74, near "my "

Comment: @Jee: I have updated my answer to avoid any "syntax error" message.

Comment: I changed my dir permissions on git home dir, recursively to 755 (tried many other lesser privileges but those did not seem to work). That seems to have resolved No Projects Found problem on web. I did not add contents of gitolite - contrib/gitweb.conf to /etc/gitweb.conf. Now i am able to browse the repositories on the web.

Comment: @Jee: excellent, but I don't think your browsing benefit from Gitolite permission management. Anyone should be able to browse your repo, even if they shouldn't according to the gitolite conf file.

Answer (score 0):

1/ install `gitolite` and set it up. Then it suffices to make sure `/home/git/.gitolite.rc` contains uncommented parts that look like:

```perl
%RC = (
    ...
    UMASK                           =>  0027,
    ...
    ENABLE => [
        ...
        'gitweb',
        ...
     ]
);
```

2/ set correctly `$projectroot` and `$projects_list` directives of `/etc/gitweb.conf` (to match location of `projects.list` file and `repositories` dir). Like:

```perl
$projectroot = "/home/git/repositories";
...
$projects_list = "/home/git/projects.list";
```

3/ Make sure current repository files are also readable by webserver user. These examples are from debian based systems, so YMMV:

```bash
sudo adduser www-data git                   # append `www-data` user to a `git` group
sudo chmod g+r /home/git/projects.list      # make sure group members can read the `project.list`
sudo chmod -R g+rx /home/git/repositories   # recursively set less restrictive access mode for group members
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart            # restart web server to apply these changes
```

4/ Finally configure access for `gitweb` user within your `/conf/gitolite.conf` file of `gitolite-admin` repository on a client machine and apply them by committing and pushing them (the standard way). A repository we would like to see and manage via `gitweb` has to have the access set like this:

```perl
repo testing                                                                    
    RW+     = @all                                                              
    R       = gitweb  # add this line to make the repo browsable using `gitweb`
```

Note: The `...` only suggests there are other configuration directives within the files. Do not put them there!

No other chages are necessary to make `gitlab` visualize the `gitolite` repositories.

Applies (at least) for `gitolite` 3.6.6 and `gitweb` 2.1.4