# Gitolite and Gitweb config acces via web

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a problem with gitolite and gitweb ...

it almost done .. but gitweb display all repos.. doesn't filter permissions for users ..

so it always show me all repos for all users..

I read that I must configure with this:

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/contrib/gitweb/gitweb.conf

but when I insert that code in my gitweb.cgi

it says:

```
Global symbol "$REPO_BASE" requires explicit package name at gitweb.cgi line 7389.
Global symbol "$REPO_BASE" requires explicit package name at gitweb.cgi line 7389.
Global symbol "$REPO_BASE" requires explicit package name at gitweb.cgi line 7389.
Execution of gitweb.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.
```

here is my gitweb.cgi

https://gist.github.com/1244184

does any one know how to make this work???

thanks..

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216176/how-do-i-have-to-configure-gitweb-and-gitolite-so-theyll-work-together help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the gitweb.conf in your /etc/ folder
at least thats what I did with it. I can see all repos I am permitted to!My Gitolite works against an AD/LDAP.