# gitweb 404 - No projects found

Tags: gitolite

I installed git + gitolite + git-daemon + gitweb setup on Ubuntu 12.04 server.
The problem is I getting always 404 - No projects found. 
I added a user called git and configured gitolite. After installing git-web added user www-data to gitolite and set chmod of project.list to g+r and repositories directory to g+rx.

```
git@aranox~$ ls -al
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  6 git  git  4096 Aug 20 16:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Aug 13 19:44 ..
-rw-------  1 git  git  1348 Aug 20 16:48 .bash_history
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 Aug 19 16:38 .cache
drwx------  8 git  git  4096 Aug 19 16:30 .gitolite
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git  4217 Aug 20 16:03 .gitolite.rc
-rw-r-----  1 git  git     0 Aug 20 16:05 projects.list
drwxr-x---  5 git  git  4096 Aug 19 16:49 repositories
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 Aug 20 16:05 .ssh
-rw-------  1 git  git   887 Aug 20 16:03 .viminfo
```

Now I changed $REPO_UMASK in my .gitolite.rc to 0077
Here my .gitolite.rc

```
# configuration variables for gitolite

# PLEASE READ THE DOCUMENTATION BEFORE EDITING OR ASKING QUESTIONS
# ( http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite.rc.mkd )
#   ( or http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/gitolite.rc.html )

# this file is in perl syntax.  However, you do NOT need to know perl to edit
# it; it should be fairly self-explanatory and easy to maintain

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DO NOT TOUCH THIS SECTION!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$GL_ADMINDIR=$ENV{HOME} . "/.gitolite";
$GL_CONF="$GL_ADMINDIR/conf/gitolite.conf";
$GL_KEYDIR="$GL_ADMINDIR/keydir";
$GL_CONF_COMPILED="$GL_ADMINDIR/conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm";

# DO NOT CHANGE THE NEXT FOUR LINES UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING.
# These variables are set automatically by the install method you choose.
#            (PACKAGE MAINTAINERS: PLEASE READ doc/packaging.mkd)
$GL_PACKAGE_CONF = "/usr/share/gitolite/conf";
$GL_PACKAGE_HOOKS = "/usr/share/gitolite/hooks";

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# most often used/changed variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$GL_WILDREPOS = 0;
$PROJECTS_LIST = $ENV{HOME} . "/projects.list";
# $WEB_INTERFACE = "gitweb";
# $GITWEB_URI_ESCAPE = 0;
$REPO_UMASK = 0027;

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# variables with an efficiency/performance impact
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$GL_BIG_CONFIG = 0;
$GL_NO_DAEMON_NO_GITWEB = 0;
# $GL_NICE_VALUE = 0;
# $BIG_INFO_CAP = 20;

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VARIABLES WITH A SECURITY IMPACT.  READ DOCS BEFORE CHANGING THESE!
# http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite.rc.mkd#_variables_with_a_security_impact
# (or http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/gitolite.rc.html#_variables_with_a_security_impact)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $GL_ALL_READ_ALL = 0;
$GIT_PATH="";
$GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS = "";
$GL_NO_CREATE_REPOS = 0;
$GL_NO_SETUP_AUTHKEYS = 0;
# $GL_WILDREPOS_DEFPERMS = 'R @all';
$HTPASSWD_FILE = "";
$RSYNC_BASE = "";
$SVNSERVE = "";

# $UPDATE_CHAINS_TO = "hooks/update.secondary";
# $ADMIN_POST_UPDATE_CHAINS_TO = "hooks/post-update.secondary";
# $GL_ADC_PATH = "";
# $GL_GET_MEMBERSHIPS_PGM = "/usr/local/bin/expand-ldap-user-to-groups"
# $GL_HTTP_ANON_USER = "mob";
# $GL_REF_OR_FILENAME_PATT=qr(^[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z._\@/+ :,-]*$);

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# less used/changed variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $GL_ALL_INCLUDES_SPECIAL = 0;
# $GL_SLAVE_MODE = 0;
# $ENV{GL_SLAVES} = 'gitolite@server2 gitolite@server3';
# PLEASE USE SINGLE QUOTES ABOVE, NOT DOUBLE QUOTES
$GL_WILDREPOS_PERM_CATS = "READERS WRITERS";
# $GL_SITE_INFO = "XYZ.COM DEVELOPERS: PLEASE SEE http://xyz.com/gitolite/help first";
# $GL_HOSTNAME = "frodo";       # read doc/mirroring.mkd COMPLETELY before setting this

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# rarely changed variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$GL_LOGT="$GL_ADMINDIR/logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log";
# $GL_PERFLOGT="$GL_ADMINDIR/logs/perf-gitolite-%y-%m.log";

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# variables that should NOT be changed after the install step completes
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$REPO_BASE="repositories";

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DO NOT TOUCH ANY THING AFTER THIS LINE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# per perl rules, this should be the last line in such a file:
1;

# Local variables:
# mode: perl
# End:
# vim: set syn=perl:
```

Next changed the $projectroot and $projects_list of my /etc/gitweb.conf and added some configurations. 
Here my gitweb.conf

```
# path to git projects (<project>.git)
$projectroot = "/home/git/repositories";

# directory to use for temp files
$git_temp = "/tmp";

# target of the home link on top of all pages
#$home_link = $my_uri || "/";

# html text to include at home page
#$home_text = "indextext.html";

# file with project list; by default, simply scan the projectroot dir.
$projects_list = "/home/git/projects.list";

# stylesheet to use
#@stylesheets = ("static/gitweb.css");

# javascript code for gitweb
#$javascript = "static/gitweb.js";

# logo to use
#$logo = "static/git-logo.png";

# the 'favicon'
#$favicon = "static/git-favicon.png";

# git-diff-tree(1) options to use for generated patches
#@diff_opts = ("-M");
@diff_opts = ();


# Enable PATH_INFO so the server can produce URLs of the
# form: http://git.cdwilson.us/project.git/xxx/xxx
# This allows for pretty URLs *within* the Git repository, where
# my Apache rewrite rules are not active.
$feature{'pathinfo'}{'default'} = [1];

$projects_list_description_width = 100;

# Enable blame, pickaxe search, snapshop, search, and grep
# support, but still allow individual projects to turn them off.
# These are features that users can use to interact with your Git trees. They
# consume some CPU whenever a user uses them, so you can turn them off if you
# need to. Note that the 'override' option means that you can override the
# setting on a per-repository basis.
$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'blame'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'pickaxe'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'pickaxe'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'snapshot'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'snapshot'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'search'}{'default'} = [1];

$feature{'grep'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'grep'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'show-sizes'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'show-sizes'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'avatar'}{'default'} = ['gravatar'];
$feature{'avatar'}{'override'} = 1;

$feature{'highlight'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'highlight'}{'override'} = 1;
```

Finally created a new vhost entry at my apache

```
<VirtualHost 88.198.64.228:80>
        ServerName git.aranox.de
        ServerAlias www.git.aranox.de
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/gitweb
        ErrorLog /var/log/vhosts/git.aranox.de_error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/vhosts/git.aranox.de_access_log combined
        <Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
                Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^.* /index.cgi/$0 [L,PT]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted apache2 and a looks fine, but still getting "No Projects found" error. I used google and search at stackoverflow, but still not found a solution. Alltime I found that the permission is wrong, but I might it ok like it is.

Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [OP Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029598/zack) mentions, `gitolite` will use the `project.list` file (also used by `gitweb`) in order to know the list of projects to parse.

> My `projects.list` was empty. Do not know why.
>   I added the repositories manually and all fine.

This is similar to this question "[Gitweb document root with gitolite](https://serverfault.com/questions/419102/gitweb-document-root-with-gitolite)", where adding the `project.list` was also enough.

---

Original answer:

Nothing in here calls directly gitolite, and the `gitolite.rc` file is a g2 (gitolite V2) file, not a [g3 one](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L308).

So first, make sure to install the latest gitolite V3 (see this [installation script for instance](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh)).

Second, git-daemon isn't needed for this setup: only an Apache server which will call the `gitweb.cgi` script: see [this `httpd.conf` config file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-78), extract below:

```
# GitWeb on @PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@
Listen @PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@
<VirtualHost @FQN@:@PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@>
ServerName @FQN@
ServerAlias @HOSTNAME@
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
DocumentRoot @H@/gitweb
Alias /git @H@/gitweb

<Directory @H@/gitweb>
  AddHandler cgi-script cgi
  DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
```

The link between gitweb and gitolite is made through a gitweb hook: if gitweb detects the presence of a `gitweb_config.perl` (like [this one](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl)), right along the other gitweb files, it will call it. I, in turn, make it call a [`gitweb.conf.pl` file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) with a function named `export_auth_hook` in it, which is a hook called by gitweb (again, if it exists).

```
$export_auth_hook = sub {
  my $repo = shift;
  my $user = $ENV{GL_USER};
  # gitweb passes us the full repo path; so we strip the beginning
  # and the end, to get the repo name as it is specified in gitolite conf
  return unless $repo =~ s/^\Q$projectroot\E\/?(.+)\.git$/$1/;

  # check for (at least) "R" permission
  my $ret = &access( $repo, $user, 'R', 'any' );
  my $res = $ret !~ /DENIED/;
  return ($ret !~ /DENIED/);
};
```

And that is it: it is enough for your gitweb to display the projects you have access to, according to the gitolite config.
This is not, however, a way to clone/push or pull git repo, as I explain in "[Missing repos in gitweb](https://serverfault.com/a/419187/783)".

Comment: I installed gito-lite using apt so I gess its the latest version, isnt it? Where to create the gitweb.conf.pl file? I didn't understand why need to do this, I am set up in /etc/gitweb.conf path to my repositories and my projects_list, giving access to the folder and file for the apache. Know there is a script required that return my repositories names? wtf

Comment: You might have another method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10810347/6309. But I prefer adding my own `gitweb.conf.pl` right along the existing `gitweb.conf`. Make sure to declare the repos you want to see in your `gitolite.conf` file: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/external.html

Comment: @Zack: sorry to hear that. I will monitor that question, hoping you will post a solution once you will have figured what the problem is in your specific context.

Comment: Found a solution. My projects.list was empty. Do not know why. I added the repositories manuel and all fine.

Comment: @Zack great! I have edited my answer to make that more visible.