# git repo description is not updating

Tags: gitolite, gitweb

In my `gitolite.conf` file I've added a bunch of `config gitweb.description` lines but I dont see the changes when I view gitweb. If I look in the repos on the server the `description` hasn't been updated.

How do I get them to sync up?

Comment: There is similar question and answer is there http://stackoverflow.com/a/13286253/458701

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the update happens on pushing that gitolite-admin repo back to the gitolite server, through [triggers](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/triggers.html).

You can manually trigger them on the server to see if that makes any difference:

```
gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE
```

Make sure the description is within a repo section:

```
repo myrepo
  config gitweb.description   =   some description
```

Double check the [content of the `projects.list` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043363/6309), and that your [`GIT_HTTP_BACKEND` is well set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783189/6309).

Comment: Hi, I've tried the `gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE` but nothing is updated. Other items are updated just fine though for example `gitweb.owner` and `gitweb.category` update when I push my gitolite-admin repo back.

Comment: @Justin808 is it possible there is some kind of  typo in your  git gitweb.description line?  What about the syntax sugar form 'descr'? Would that work better? And what version of gitolite are you using?